# Refresh listview with new JSON objects?

Tags: android, json, listview, twitter, custom-adapter

My listview is designed to add results straight from the JSONArray. Is there any way I can make it to where it only adds items that don't already exist in the listview? I'm using a custom adapter.

**getTweets AsyncTask**

```
public class getTweets extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    int counter;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BufferedReader reader =null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=40");
            ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().signRequest(get);
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
            String result2 = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result2);
            for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject session = array.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject profilePic = session.getJSONObject("user");
                addTweet(profilePic.getString("name"),profilePic.getString("screen_name"),session.getString("text"),profilePic.getString("profile_image_url"));
            }
            }catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("TwitterFeedActivity", "Error loading JSON", e);

}
        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tweetListView.setAdapter(tweetAdapter);
        return;
   }


}
public void addTweet(String user,String mentionname,String tweet,String profile_picture){
    tweetAdapter.add(new TweetList(user,mentionname, tweet,profile_picture));
}
```

**ListView Adapter**

```
public class TweetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private TextView tweet,twitterUser,twitterMention;
    ImageView profile_picture;
    private List<TweetList> tweetList = new ArrayList<TweetList>();


    public void add(TweetList object) {
        tweetList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    public TweetArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.tweetList.size();
    }

    public TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return this.tweetList.get(position);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet_list_item, parent, false);
            twitterUser = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            tweet = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.display_tweet);
            twitterMention = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_twitter_mentionname);
            profile_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);

            TweetList tweetMessageObj = getItem(position);
            SpannableString hashtag = new SpannableString(tweetMessageObj.tweet);
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            while (matcher.find())
            {
                hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            }
            while (matcher2.find())
            { hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
            }
            tweet.setText(hashtag, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            tweet.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            tweet.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            tweet.setTypeface(tf);
            Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
            twitterUser.setText(tweetMessageObj.twittername);
            twitterUser.setTypeface(tf2);
            twitterMention.setText("@" + tweetMessageObj.mentionname);
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.pictureURL).resize(400,400).into(profile_picture);
        return row;
    }


}
```

**TweetsList**

```
public class TweetList {
    public String twittername,mentionname,tweet,pictureURL;



    public TweetList(String twittername,String mentionname,String tweet,String pictureURL) {
        super();
        this.twittername = twittername;
        this.tweet = tweet;
        this.pictureURL = pictureURL;
        this.mentionname = mentionname;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think of is to get another ArrayList,

```
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then add and filter it simultaneously,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject session = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject profilePic = session.getJSONObject("user");
        if (mArrayList.contains(profilePic.getString("name"))) {
            mArrayList.add(profilePic.getString("name"));
            addTweet(profilePic.getString("name"),
                    profilePic.getString("screen_name"),
                    session.getString("text"),
                    profilePic.getString("profile_image_url"));
        }
    }
```

You can filter any string parameter you want in these lines,

```
            if (mArrayList.contains(profilePic.getString("name")))
            mArrayList.add(profilePic.getString("name"));
```

Comment: Works great,but for some reason it adds the new ones to the bottom. Any clue?

Comment: Where do u want to add new one??  Or if you do not want previous data then clear adapter and array list onpreExecute method of async class.

Comment: I want the new data to load on the very top of the listview while keeping the previous data.

Comment: Crazy idea but, just try to do with reverse for loop means leangth to 0. Or why dont you send data from server in soryed order.